# Accessing a class of iPhone app in Watch App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, watchkit

I want to use my already developed `NSObject` Class in watch app (Watch App target is added to same project).

My iPhone App is written in Objective-C and now I am using Swift for Watch Extension, so I created a *Bridge-Header* to use this class in Watch App and add the class to Watch Extension target. When I build the app, it gives me many errors from other classes with this reason:

> Cannot find interface declaration for `UIControllerView`, SuperClass of xxxxClass

And all these error files seem that they have a target of WatchKit Extension, but I didn't include them. On these files, *Target Membership* Watch Extension is also unchecked (means not a target of extension). Here are the Classes which I didn't added to Watch Extension, but they are running as a Watch Extension class.

[image]

Comment: UIKit classes like `UIViewController` simply don't exist in WatchKit.

Comment: @PetahChristian i did not added them.Don't know why they are referenced. i added only NSObject Class Target to Watch Extension. These Classes compile with my Class in watchApp as a unwanted guest.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to select that class and check Target membership for WatchKit extension From file inspector.

For Swift class :

[image]

For Objective-C class you make it for .m file

Comment: yes i have done this thing. Completed all the steps.. if i do same procedure in new project it is running fine with no error and sharing that class.. only problem with this project.. might be some setting or something else.

Comment: @Ali You need to know that you cannot use UIKit classes in your Apple Watch application ! So UIView or UIViewController is included in UIKit framework , you cannot use them in Apple Watch app which work WatchKit framework instead.

Comment: @Aaoli i know i can not use it in watch app and i did not added these classes to watchkit extension but my project drag these classes to watch app automatically.. i have added only One class which is NSObject Class

Answer (score 0):

You have the check the targeting files are added or not.

For that:

1.select your project file -->Build Phase-->Compile Sources.

```
  -Check the file present or not.
```

2.if not just remove and add the files that are all missing in compile source.

3.Clean and Build your source..

Comment: File is present in Compile Sources (which i want to add). But Problem is my project compiling those file which i have not added to the Watch Extension. that generate the errors.